# Laravel 7 + vuejs multiple authentication /admin route is not working

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication

I'm new to vuejs, i preparing a laravel 7 multiple auth work. In this work, i do the frontend part with vuejs. The problem is that the route part:

`Route::get('/{any}/', 'Front\IndexController@index')->where('any', '. *');`

When I write this to `routes \ web` and enter `localhost:8000/admin` or `localhost:8000/admin/register` the admin page does not appear but when I type `localhost:8000/login` or `localhost:8000/register` there is no problem.
If I delete the route part, admin page is working but this time vuejs routes give a 404 error whenever I refresh the page.

Can't we do something like this:

`Route::get('/{any}/', 'Front\IndexController@index')->where('any', '. *-Not-> /admin/ and /admin/login/ and /admin/register and /admin/index and /admin/user etc.');`

I did the work based on this project:
https://github.com/samironbarai/laravel-7-multi-auth.git

Answer (score -1):

Finally i solved the problem.
1-Deleting this:`Route::get('/{any}/', 'Front\IndexController@index')->where('any', '. *');` in route\web.php.
2-[Delete this on app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiEUs.png)

3- [Paste this on app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlsvR.png)

[and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pth4.png)

Since I am new to Stackoverflow, I couldn't explaining it well but that's how I solved it.